# PostgreeSQL + Hibernate: threw an unexpected exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@'

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Здравствуйте.
В консоли PostgreeSQL пишу такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM public.mynotes
WHERE to_tsvector('russian', atext) @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'вышел заяц');
```

Работает корректно.

В Java-приложении есть метод который "собирает" ту же самую строку запроса и отдает её Hibernate:

```
@Override
public List<MynotesEntity> getSearchList(String lang, String phrase){

    String qString = "from MynotesEntity where to_tsvector (" +
                     lang + ", atext) @@ plainto_tsquery(" + lang + ", " + phrase + ")";
    Query query = session.createQuery(qString);
    mynotesEntityList = query.list();
    return mynotesEntityList;
}
```

Причем два символа "@@" подчеркнуты красным, но тем не менее приложение запускается.
Как только дело доходит до вызова метода, получаю исключение:

```
threw an unexpected exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@' [from ru.javastudy.gwtPersistence.shared.MynotesEntity where to_tsvector ('russian', atext) @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'вышел заяц')]
```

Я так понимаю, что `hibernate` не знает символов @@ ?!
Что мне делать в таком случае?

Comment: Видимо, придется в ручную регистрировать этот функционал: http://grails-dev.blogspot.ru/2014/10/adding-custom-operators-in-hql-for.html

Comment: Как же всё не просто. А что общего с полнотекстовым поиском PostgreSQL имеет Hibernate Search?

Comment: session.createQuery(qString); - Это же квери на языке HQL (или как он там точно называется)? У него наверное нет специфических функций postgres. Надо искать способы задать native запрос. Как в JPA запросы JPQL - createQuery, нативные SQL - createNativeQuery. Кстати Hibernate имеет и JPA-интерфейс, но не знаю можно ли его совмещать с родным

Comment: Да как то странно получается. Вроде везде в конфигах я декларирую поддержку PostgreSQL. И в запросах использую (как я думал) PostgreSQL. Видимо Hibernate "думает" что я использую HQL и, в связи с чем, не понимает специфических PostgreSQL - выражений.

Comment: Поддержка того или иного сервера не подразумевает поддержку каких-то очень специфических особенностей. Поддерживается только те, аналоги которых есть в самом hibernate. Да и то не все. Например пагинация. Mysql - `SELECT ... LIMIT 10, 30` Postgres - `SELET * LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30`. Firebird - `SELECT FIRST 10 SKIP 30 ...` и т.д. Вот такие разные штуки поддержкой сводятся к одной  финкции общей для всех. Есть в hibernate полнотекстовый поиск? Как он пишется на общем языке?

Comment: попробуйте [session.createSQLQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-jpa-query)

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает. Решил эту задачку при помощи Hibernate Search.